# mobile web service server

Tags: web-services, windows-mobile

I have a device running on windowse ce 6.0 I would like the customer to be able go to  the device ip and see simlpe reports or change basic settings.
is there is an option in the device to have a simpe asp web site? or only a web service to download an xml file with whats going on in the device?

I dont want to put this information in a server, I want the client to go direct to his device.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [commercial product called Padarn](http://www.opennetcf.com/Products/Padarn.aspx) that is a lightweight ASP.NET Web Server that could do it.

For full disclosure, I'm the one who wrote and is selling Padarn.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a web server for WM that does special things on the device if the device's web site is invoked with args. The code can make the device beep or do report some information of the device.

I can post the code etc, if you like.

~josef

Comment: Done: see http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2012/10/19/windows-mobile-a-simple-web-server-with-extended-features/